# Why is a part of my where clause not used in my conditional function?

Tags: haskell

I've been practicing Haskell as part of my course at my university, and I made the following function while experimenting with local definitions :

```
fac1 x | x == 0 = zero
       | x == 1 = one
       | otherwise = x * fac1 (x-1)
         where zero = 0
               one = 1
```

I would expect any call to fac1 result in zero because when x==0, it will multiply by 0. However, it gives me the correct number.

Conversely, writing `one = 0` instead of `one = 1` results in my results being 0. I would expect the same sort of behavior for zero, but changing the value of it does nothing. I feel like it should be happening since I clearly included a `x==0` condition. The `x==1` is evaluated, why not `x==0`?

Can someone explain what error I made?

Comment: By the way, [`0!` is `1`](https://www.google.com/search?q=0!).

Comment: @4castle I know, I was purposely trying to do this. It insults me a little.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your recursion stops on `x = 1`, not `x = 0`.

Let's evaluate `fac1 2` by hand:

```
fac1 2
  = 2 * fac1 (2 - 1) -- 2 is neither 0 nor 1, so we take the "otherwise" case
  = 2 * fac1 1       -- evaluate 2 - 1
  = 2 * one          -- x == 1 holds, so we return "one"
  = 2 * 1            -- one is 1
  = 2                -- done
```

Comment: Now that I look at it, you are completely right. Wow, I'm pretty ashamed.

Comment: @Zeta could OP delete the question if you delete the answer? (not saying you should)

Comment: @גלעדברקן  [Yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Comment: @chi Neither do I, I just answered on a (now deleted) comment whether the question can get deleted. Either way, we're slightly getting off-topic on the comment train itself, so I'll remove the question deletion comment ^^.